# Samsung GT-i9300, JellyBean, Headset button changing sound profile

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, headset

I'm running Android 4.1.1 stock firmware (JellyBean) on my Samsung GT-i9300.

After updating, I'm having some issues with headset controls. I am using the official Samsung headset which came with my phone.

The issue with long press opening Google Now is annoying, but it doesn't seem to have a solution that I can find. However, when I press the pause/play button on my headset, it changes my sound profile to Normal - this is really annoying as I tend to listen to music in work, and need to keep manually changing my profile to vibrate after EVERY time I play/pause/skip a track.

I've tried using the Jays Headset Controls app to no avail... does anyone have any idea on what I could do to fix this issue?